# if statement in MATLAB for plotting the height of a ball

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB to calculate the height of a ball in case of projectile motion. Here is my code :

```
v    = 10; 
teta = 20; % angle of the projectile motion
vx   = v*cos(teta); % velocity in x axis
vy   = v*sin(teta); % velocity in y axis
x    = 0:10;
y    = zeros(length(x),1);

for xx=1:length(x)

    % here I calculate the height of the ball in y axis
    y(xx,:) = vy*(xx/vx)-(0.5*9.81*(xx./vx)^2); 

    % here I want to break the system when the height of the ball is 
    % zero (on the ground surface)
    if y(xx,:) == 0 
        break
    end
end

plot(x,y, '*')
```

The problem that when I plot the motion it does not stop when the height is zero
but it continues for negative values of `y` axis ..

What is the wrong in my `if`-statement?

Comment: You could just calculate all the values without breaking the for loop and then just plot the values you need, i.e. `plot(x(y>=0),y(y>=0),'*');`

Comment: On a side note, you don't have to write `y(xx,:)` when the size of `y` along the second dimension is 1. Actually, MATLAB's sees every variable as `size1*size2*.....*sizeN*1*1*1*1*1*1*1.....` variables.

Comment: thank you very much .. I got the plot and it starts from height of 2 , Should not it start from height 0 ?

Comment: Well, if you want your initial height to be `0`, wouldn't you want your initial `xx` to be `0`?

Comment: yes I have it 0 ,,, here `x=0:10;`

Comment: Yes, but the variable in your for loop is `xx` that goes from `1` to `length(x)`

Comment: when I changed for loop xx to 0 to length(x) I got : `Attempted to access y(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.`

Comment: See Crowley's answer for the solution you're seeking (I'm sure it will be edited in a minute)

Comment: @BillBokeey How did you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `for` loop at all:

```
v=10; 
theta=20; % angle of the projectile motion
vx=v*cos(theta); % velocity in x axis
vy=v*sin(theta); % velocity in y axis
x=0:0.1:10;
y=zeros(size(x));

y=vy.*(x./vx)-(0.5*9.81*(x./vx).^2);    %% Calculate values for all x
x=x(y>=0);                             %% keep the x values where y>=0
y=y(y>=0);                             %% keep the y valuse where y>=0

plot(x,y,'*')
```

Comment: thank you very much .. I got the plot and it shows the x axis from 0 to 7 and I do not see the end of the curve when the height of boll should be zero in the end of the curve ?? why it does not show the end when the height is zero ?? I even changed the length of x vector but I got same result

Comment: It's because next point is below the 0. It's value is `-0.0102`. To get the point `[x,0]` you have to extrapolate the point.

Comment: If you want only to **see** the curve above 0, forget about any `x=x(y>0)` stuff and use `set(gca,'ylim',[0,5])` after the `plot` command...

Comment: o my dear God ... thank you very very much ..  God bless you ,, you are really cleaver .. many thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You should never compare a float or double number to an integer. When you say `if y(xx,:)== 0` you are breaking the loop only when the height is exactly zero, and that will never happen (just see the values stored in y).

If you want to keep your data from been negative, you should try `if y(xx,:) < 0`. Keep in mind that if you use this approach, you should always delete the last value added to y, because when that statement breaks you loop, you've already stored the first negative value. So, just add `y(xx)= 0;` before the break line.

Comment: thank you very much .. I got the plot and it starts from height of 2 , Should not it start from height 0 ?

Comment: I think you are incorrectly using the iterator xx as if it was the x-lenght. Try using `y(xx,:)=vy*(x(xx)/vx)-(0.5*9.81*(x(xx)./vx)^2)`. In the future you should avoid similar names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`<teacher_mode>`

What I would do is use constant *time* increments rather than using constant `x` increments. This is not only more intuitive, but also provides a much better building block for if you'd want to level up in the future. This approach makes it easier to include additional effects (like airdrag, 3D, bounces, ...) and is a stepping stone towards more advanced methods to do these computations (numerical integration of the vector-valued equations of motion; see `ode45` in MATLAB for some examples).

Here is an example of a "bouncy" ball:

```
v     = 100; % initial speed
theta = 20;  % initial angle (°) with X-axis

vx    = v * cosd(theta); % initial velocity in x axis
vy    = v * sind(theta); % initial velocity in y axis

T     = 0 : 0.01 : 50;   % times to sample

x = zeros(length(T),1);
y = zeros(length(T),1);

ay = -9.80665; % gravity
ax = 0;        % ...wind perhaps

ex = 0.9;      % elasticity in X-direction
ey = 0.5;      % elasticity in Y-direction


for ii = 2:numel(T)

    % Update time step        
    dt = T(ii)  -T(ii-1);

    % Update speed    
    vx = vx + ax*dt;
    vy = vy + ay*dt;

    % Update position 
    x(ii) = x(ii-1) + [vx ax/2] * dt.^(1:2)';
    y(ii) = y(ii-1) + [vy ay/2] * dt.^(1:2)';

    % Bounce the ball!
    if y(ii) <= 0 
        y(ii) = 0;
        vx = ex* vx;
        vy = abs( ey*vy );
    end

end

clf, hold on
plot(x,y)
```

[image: a bouncy ball]

`</teacher_mode>`